# How to keep focus on input field after browser repaint?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have multiple tabs and each tab has its own iframe. During the first rendering tab 1's input text field has focus using JQuery. After switching to tab 2 and coming back on tab 1 does not put back focus on the input field from tab 1.

As per my understanding focus will be set during DOM construction phase and will be rendered by the browser as it is. But on repaint no DOM re-construction happens so JQuery can not put back focus on the input field.

```
function clearSearchTxtInput(resetResults) {
        $("#searchTxt").val('');
        $("#searchTxt").focus();
 }
```

Above code is called onload.

Is there a non-blocking way to put back focus on the input field?

Comment: `IFRAME.on('load', function(){ //do something with input element; })`

Comment: Will it be called on repaint? During tab switch first iframe is only hidden and switching it back will not cause a reload.

Comment: Ooh, then how are you switching between tabs ? Some JavaScript ?

Comment: Yes On tab switch hide the iframe of first tab and load the content of second tab on new iframe.

Comment: After `.show()`, set the `.focus()` on the `input` element..

Comment: That will only work on the first render but not on the repaint.

Comment: You could write some smart code to make it work on all the input element after switch...but you must have some pattern between input elements./...

Comment: I am thinking of setTimeout function which will put back focus on input field.

Comment: I doubt you will need that...Share some of your code to get a better view...

Comment: Code added to the question.

Comment: Add `focus()` after visibility(`show()`) is updated..

Comment: Can you please provide an example?

Comment: Sure..Kindly share the fiddle to demonstrate the issue...

Comment: Thanks for your help, it wil take a while to prepare the fiddle.